# Power BI Desktop loading from Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 returning 500 Operation could not be completed within the specified time

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-storage, azure-data-lake, powerbi-desktop

We are storing files in a Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 container with the folder structure *year*/*month*/*day*/*datasource*/*filename*.csv. At the moment we have data stored for a handful of datasources and about 15 days of data. So we have 75 leaf folders and they contain 3 files each. The files are about 200-500kB.

When using Power BI Desktop -> Load data -> Azure Storage Data Lake Gen2 and enter the url of the container, the operation will take a while and then show the error message (translated to english by me):

> Information: AzureDataLakeStorage could not fetch content from https://ourstorageaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/ourcontainer. Status code: 500. Description: Operation could not be completed within the specified time.

How can I debug this problem?

Comment: Did the error solved now?

Comment: No. Also opened a ticket here https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy/issues/889